# Is it OK to declare a DBSet in the context for both a base table and a derived table?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a SalesOrder table which inherits from a SalesDocument table using Table Per Type Inheritance

The ( simplified) table classes are;

```
[Table("SalesDocumentHeaders")]
public abstract class SalesDocumentHeader  
{
[ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

[Required]
public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public String ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

} 

[Table("SalesOrders")]
public class SalesOrder : SalesDocumentHeader
{
[Required]
public String CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }

public DateTime? DeliverBy { get; set; }

public virtual SortableBindingList<SalesOrderLine> Lines { get; set; }

}
```

The context contains

```
public DbSet<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }

public DbSet<SalesDocumentHeader> SalesDocumentHeaders { get; set; }
```

It doesn't strictly need the SalesOrders DBSet, since SalesOrder inherits from SalesDocumentHeader  however I find it convenient.

It seems to work OK, but I am worried that there are 2 ways of reaching the same record , am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you only need to keep the DBSet for the base table. This helps when you have multiple derived tables (call them A and B) and you need to decide the actual type dynamically.

For example if you have another entity which references type A or B (like a user can have different types of contact information), you can reference the base table and EF will resolve the correct concrete type at runtime. Though of course this adds some extra casting code.

Comment: suppose i want a list of type A, how do I get that?  Also will my method of having 2 DBSets cause bugs?

Comment: @kirsteng You can use `context.BaseType.OfType<TypeA>()` to get all entities of type A. Your method should be OK as long as there's only one derived type, but I've never tried this. Why do you want to keep 2 DBSets when you only need one and the base type is abstract?